# Lookup table for 2 pairs of data in R

Tags: r, lookup

I did a lookup table for 2 pairs of data in R

Data test:

```
T   RH
32  0
45  12
36  15
29  25
28  35
```

Lookup Tabel (only some listed here):

```
32  11  3.95
32  12  3.9
32  13  3.85
32  14  3.8
32  15  3.75
32  16  3.7
```

but the data that does not match with the lookup table is dropped in the output

how to make the output have the same size of rows and with NA in the rows of output that are not matched to the lookup table?

btw my code is this:

```
A1 <- data-tes
B1 <- lookup

library(dplyr)

anti_join(anti_join(B1, A1 )) %>%
  select(-Rate)

TCI2 <- bind_rows(inner_join(B1, A1 ))
```

---

Sorry I mean like this:

Data test:
T   RH
32  0
45  12
36  15
29  25
28  35

Look up Table:
T   RH   Rate
32  0     5
45  12    4
70  15    3
80  25    2

Output desired:
T   RH  Rate
32  0     5
45  12    4
36  15    NA
29  25    NA
28  35    NA

NA because not mathced with Lookup Table

Comment: What's the desired output for this same? How many rows should be in the output? Are you trying to match only on `T` or on `T` and `RH`? It's not clear exactly what you want. Perhaps you want a `left_join`?

Comment: This sounds like a `left_join` to me. I'm not clear on they keys by which you want to join though. Your `lookup` has no column names. Do you want to join by the first columns of `data-tes` and `lookup`? Or the first two columns? Or ...? What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit:

Thanks for updating your question with more details, but please edit your original question to include the new details rather than adding them in a comment.

It looks like you want a 'left join' (as suggested by @Maurits Evers in the comment above), e.g.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

A1 <- read.table(text = "T   RH
32  0
45  12
36  15
29  25
28  35 ", header = TRUE)

B1 <- read.table(text = "T   RH   Rate
32  0     5
45  12    4
70  15    3
80  25    2", header = TRUE)

desired_outcome <- read.table(text = "T   RH  Rate
32  0     5
45  12    4
36  15    NA
29  25    NA
28  35    NA", header = TRUE)

left_join(A1, B1)
#> Joining, by = c("T", "RH")
#>    T RH Rate
#> 1 32  0    5
#> 2 45 12    4
#> 3 36 15   NA
#> 4 29 25   NA
#> 5 28 35   NA
desired_outcome
#>    T RH Rate
#> 1 32  0    5
#> 2 45 12    4
#> 3 36 15   NA
#> 4 29 25   NA
#> 5 28 35   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Sorry I mean like this:

Data test:
T   RH
32  0
45  12
36  15
29  25
28  35 

Look up Table:
T   RH   Rate
32  0     5
45  12    4
70  15    3
80  25    2


Output desired:
T   RH  Rate
32  0     5
45  12    4
36  15    NA
29  25    NA
28  35    NA

NA because not mathced with Lookup Table